# Chrome rewrites font's built-in letter-spacing for uppercase text

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, letter-spacing

I have a font, that have a built-in tracking for uppercase text.
This is how it is look like without any tweaks in Safari and Firefox, and enabled [font-feature-setting: 'liga'](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/1789736-syntax-for-opentype-features-in-css#liga) for Chrome

After that I am trying to manually set letter-spacing of the text:
letter-spacing: 0.01em.

It looks like Safari and Firefox increasing that built-in letter-spacing by letter-spacing that I defined manually. So the text looks almost like before.

But Chrome (and all Chromium based browsers) seems to rewriting that value.

Illustration: http://d.pr/i/rn5O (Sorry, cant post images yet).

Is it possible to unify behaviour of letter-spacing across these browsers?